# How to read a spreadsheet using Google Sheets API + Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

There's a nice solution to updating Google spreadsheets using the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575850/how-to-update-spreadsheet-using-google-sheets-api-javascript).

It overwrites the current contents. I'd like to read in the current contents, modify them, then update.

How do I read in the current spreadsheet?

Comment: Have you tried reading the rest of [that linked documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get)? Or did you want us to just write the code for you?

Comment: I tried GET, which is described as "Gets a file's metadata or content by ID". That works fine, but only seems to return metadata, not the actual content. (I used an $.ajax() call, with url of "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + SHEET_ID + "?key=" + API_KEY; for anyone interested).

Answer (score 0):

This works (assuming your credentials are in order and you are authorized):

```
function getFileInfo(fileId, callback) {
    try {
        gapi.client.drive.files.get({
            fileId: fileId,
            fields: "appProperties,capabilities,contentHints,createdTime,description,explicitlyTrashed,fileExtension,folderColorRgb,fullFileExtension,headRevisionId,iconLink,id,imageMediaMetadata,isAppAuthorized,kind,lastModifyingUser,md5Checksum,mimeType,modifiedByMeTime,modifiedTime,name,originalFilename,ownedByMe,owners,parents,permissions,properties,quotaBytesUsed,shared,sharedWithMeTime,sharingUser,size,spaces,starred,thumbnailLink,trashed,version,videoMediaMetadata,viewedByMe,viewedByMeTime,viewersCanCopyContent,webContentLink,webViewLink,writersCanShare",
        }).then(function(response) {
            info = JSON.parse(response.body);
            callback(info);
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Something bad happened: ' + err);
    }
}
```

It returns all the known metadata fields (as of this time). You'll want to trim back the list to those you need. But it does not return the actual spreadsheet contents. For that, you'll need to use the [export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export) api:

```
function getSpreadsheet(fileId, callback) {
    var spreadsheet;
    try {
        gapi.client.drive.files.export({
            fileId: fileId,
            mimeType: 'text/csv'
        }).then(function(response) {
            spreadsheet = Papa.parse(response.body).data;
            callback(spreadsheet);
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Something bad happened: ' + err);
    }
}
```

The data is return as a csv string. We use [Papa.parse](http://papaparse.com/) to turn it into a 2D array.